# Handling jQuery click events on divs produced in a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML `div`:

```
<div id='text_icon_<?php $i++; ?>' class="text_icon">Some Text</div>
```

that I print inside a `foreach` loop. I am using ajax to handle the `click()` event on it and change its text to `Done!`, so I have an output like:

```
<div class="text">Done!</div>
```

If I run the loop 4 times and I click on one of the `div`s (i.e. the one with class `text_icon`) then only first one is working while the rest of the `div`s are not working.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code involved, it will not be possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: please provide the code of your loop.

Comment: Could you please post your jQuery and PHP code? I can't do much without it...

Comment: Have you compared the 4 divs in Firebug?

Comment: I rewrote your post for clarity, please re-read and make sure that I've adequately captured what you were trying to accomplish.  Also, it's evident after rewriting that you're not giving us quite enough information to help you, how about showing us your jQuery code?

Comment: @Mark: It looks to me like you inadvertently removed a pretty important thing: Pushpendra added text showing him using an `i` variable PHP-side to give each div a unique ID.

Comment: @T.J. I added it back in -- the change Pushpendra added reverted all the other cleanup, so I rolled-back and pushed another change. Refresh?

Comment: @Mark: I refreshed before commenting. It's there now, though.

Comment: AJAX does not handle events. Javascript handles events.

Comment: @Pushpendra: Since it's not the ID issue, I've updated my answer. But again, as people have said, without **your** jQuery code, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Your update indicates the below is not the problem, the IDs are unique.

Without **your** jQuery code it's hard to help you debug, so here's an example of how it *can* be done:

HTML:

```
<div id='text_icon1' class='text_icon'>Div #1</div>
<div id='text_icon2' class='text_icon'>Div #2</div>
<div id='text_icon3' class='text_icon'>Div #3</div>
<div id='text_icon4' class='text_icon'>Div #4</div>
```

JavaScript code using jQuery:

```
$("div.text_icon").click(function() {

  // Within the `click` handler, `this` points to the
  // DOM element. If you're kicking off some ajax something,
  // you'll probably be doing something like this:

  // Grab `this` to a variable we can access from the
  // `success` closure
  var theDiv = this;

  // Do our call
  $.ajax({
    url: "your_url_here",
    success: function() {
      // It worked, udate the div
      $(theDiv).text("Done!");
    }
  });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/efebi4)

---

Original answer:

If you're really using "DIV id='text_icon' class="text_icon..../DIV", e.g.:

```
<DIV id='text_icon' class="text_icon">....</DIV>
```

...then the problem is that the `id` is not unique. ID values **must** be unique on the page ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#concept-id)). That would seem to fit with the symptom you describe, with "only the first one" working. Most browsers, when given invalid HTML with multiple IDs, will use the ID on the first element in document order and ignore the remaining ones.

If you don't need the div to have an ID at all, you can just remove it. Otherwise, just ensure the ID is unique, e.g.:

```
<DIV id='text_icon1' class="text_icon">....</DIV>
<DIV id='text_icon2' class="text_icon">....</DIV>
<DIV id='text_icon3' class="text_icon">....</DIV>
<DIV id='text_icon4' class="text_icon">....</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are giving your divs the same ID. Targetting multiple elements with the same ID is impossible, the IDs need to be unique.

Try this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $al) {
    echo "<div id='text_icon_$i'>blablabla</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to modify your jQuery code too to include a potentially unlimited number of such IDs (I don't know whether performance will be good this way, but I remember doing it once for a comments list on a blog).

Another way would be to use a common class rather than unique IDs :).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the arguments about unique IDs, could it also be that the click handlers need to be hooked up again after the ajax call? If so, it'd be better to use .live rather than .click.

```
$("div.text_icon").live("click",
    function(event) { 
         var icon = $(this); 
    } 
}
```